# MacBook Pro with external monitor

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro, macos-highsierra

I've just tried connecting to my 2011 MacBookPro two different external displays (hp zr2440w and Dell U2414H UltraSharp 24 Full HD monitors, just one at the same time) with the connection of this product: https://lanberg.pl/en/produkt/AD-0005-BK and normal HDMI-cable but the problem is the same: I can clearly see how the screen light similarly to when the night mode settings turned on so the white background isn't white, its yellowish instead but I didn't turned on anything. Also I can't find where to turn it on or off in High Sierra.

Could anyone help, please?

Comment: If you had a compatible display and the right cable or adapter, it should have just worked. There's no place to enable or disable support for external displays. It's always enabled. To make progress on this problem, you will probably need to edit your question to include the make and model of each display, and what kind of cable/adapter setup you used to connect the Mac to each display. Also, if your displays had multiple input ports, did you use the buttons on the display to switch to the correct input? Maybe your displays don't support auto-switching to a newly-active input.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've updated my post!